# Exclude Shipping Tax in grand total

Tags: magento-1.8, shipping, invoice, totals, grand-total

I'm stuck trying to exclude the shipping cost from the order-totals table in the invoice email.

At the moment, the invoice email looks like this: (I included a little translation for the most important fields)

[image: current result]

As you can see: the grand total (15.80€) includes the shipping tax (6.20€).

Is it possible (and if, how) to change the grand total to **exclude** the shipping cost?

I've made a small mockup below:

[image: required result]

Do I need to edit template files? Or should I target the GrandTotal calculation in the model?

I'm using Magento 1.8.

I very much appreciate any help regarding this issue.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

usually we do in the following way

do a local ovveride of app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Totals.php

and look for the function

```
public function renderTotal($total, $area = null, $colspan = 1)
{
    $code = $total->getCode();
    if ($total->getAs()) {
        $code = $total->getAs();
    }
    if($code == 'code_to_skip')
        return(''); //does not rendere the unwanted total row
    return $this->_getTotalRenderer($code)
        ->setTotal($total)
        ->setColspan($colspan)
        ->setRenderingArea(is_null($area) ? -1 : $area)
        ->toHtml();
}
```

this is the function that renders the totals to html check the $code by logging them and skip the unwanted one

hope this help

Comment: Does this file also render the totals in the magento invoice emails?

Comment: the above is for the cart, you should look into app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Block\Order

Answer (score 0):

Go To

> System > configuration

In the left sidebar

> Sales > Shipping Methods :

*Enable Free Shipping* and disable the one's that are not required

Comment: I can't disable it unfortunately. :( I just want to change the position of "Shipping" in the order mail. I don't know where it magento generates the HTML for the order-email totals table.

Comment: magento\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\checkout\onepage\review\info.phtml : This is where the design come from

Comment: I checked it. It's the table on the onepage-checkout. I tried to edit it but the order email still looks the same. :(

Comment: I am sorry, you want to remove this from code?
Or from cart step?
Do you need shipping, or you just want to comment the code fromwhere it is coming?